# tmux build failure

Tags: tmux

server-fn.o: In function `server_destroy_pane':
server-fn.c:(.text+0x8ec): undefined reference to`utempter_remove_record'
window.o: In function `window_pane_spawn':
window.c:(.text+0x356c): undefined reference to`utempter_add_record'
window.o: In function `window_pane_destroy':
window.c:(.text+0x3730): undefined reference to`utempter_remove_record'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: I do not have root access and I have to build this locally. I was able to build and include libevent and ncurses successfully. I'm trying to install tmux on an SLES 10 machine. I really appreciate any assistance with this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message indicates that it is looking for a development version of libutempter.

As a starting point, keep in mind the RPM package which could have been installed if you had permissions.  That shows where to get a source (as well as possible fixes for problems building with your environment): [utempter 0.5.5](https://www.suse.com/LinuxPackages/packageRouter.jsp?product=server&version=10&service_pack=sp3&architecture=x86_64&package_name=utempter).  Actually *that* version is rather old (see for example the versions cited in [RPMfind](http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libutempter.so.0)).  Looking for a newer version of the source-rpm `utempter-1.1.6-3.1.2.src.rpm` finds a few copies via [rpmfind.net](http://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/opensuse/13.1/x86_64/libutempter0-1.1.6-3.1.2.x86_64.html) and via [pbone.net](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/25031951/dir/opensuse_13.x/com/libutempter0-1.1.6-3.1.2.i586.rpm.html).  The latter points to an [ftp-directory](ftp://ftp.altlinux.org/pub/people/ldv/utempter/) with a few versions to choose from.

You can either extract the source (and patches) from a source-rpm using `unrpm`, or just build from the tarballs from the ftp-directory.